# DVD Player: Google TV Channel Listing

Tags: television

- What do channel listing (and channel changing) APIs return when a DVD player is connected to the google tv box's HDMI in.
- Is there a way to pause the stream from the DVD player by playing with the Intent?

Sample app: http://code.google.com/p/googletv-android-samples/source/browse/#git%2FChannelChangingSample

Sorry, I don't have access google tv or emulator (too slow to try anything). Otherwise, I could have tried this out myself.